# Including Swift framework which uses cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, ios-frameworks

I'm building a swift Framework (SharedFramework) to include it later in my iOS project.

Now my swift framework needs to use cocoapods to include libraries like SwiftyJSON. So I did a pod init added SwiftyJSON, everything works file in the framework. (I Tested it, it works)

Now when I try to add this framework into my iOS App (A different project):

- I drag the SharedFramework.xcodeproj from the finder to my iOS app.
- Then **iOS app** > **Target** > **Build phase** > **Target Dependencies** (add)
- And Then Then **iOS app** > **Target** > **General** > **Embedded Binaries** (add)

Now if I try to build it says **Build Failed**.

The iOS project cannot find the Framework 'SwiftyJSON', which is a library for my 'SharedFramework'.

[image: Error ! Cannot find the framework]

FYI: I repeat the same above process with a swift Framework which does not use cocoapods it work fine.

Comment: Hi @spaceMonkey, Did you get an answer for this? Am having the same issue.

Comment: @Sathya no but i realised this is not recommended approach. So i changed my solution. I change my cocopods of the top level such that my swift library and my iOS project use the same pods.
Because lets say you are using SwfityJSON in both your projects (iOS and Shared Lib) its better to use one pod for it and point at both the projects